# How to remove a specific part of string on a specific field on table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Today I discovered that on my production database the field `name` of some record also contains `&nbsp`, so there are thousands of record that contains in `name` field this type of structure: `Mamurrasi vs. Internacional Tirana&nbsp;`

So I am wondering if I can remove `&nbsp;` from this record without damage the database.

For find it I used: 
    SELECT * 
    FROM venue 
    WHERE name LIKE "%&nbsp%"`

Comment: Can you [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it?

Comment: you can `trim` the table column by `update` .. But before doing any operation on table please take backup of your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace:

```
update venue
    set name = trim(replace(name, '&nbsp', ' '))
    where name like '%&nbsp%';
```

This replace `&nbsp` with a space and then removes unnecessary spaces from the beginning and end of the string.

`&nbsp` is the html code for a non-breaking space.  It makes more sense to replace it with a space than to to remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is Oracle and you want to replace `'&nbsp;'` by `' '`:

```
UPDATE venue v SET v.name = REPLACE(v.name, '&nbsp;', ' ');
```